# Drupal7 - Views: Different count of elements per page

Tags: 7, views, paging, nodes

I have an view for displaying 28 contentelements(teaser). (7 rows á 4 elements)
Now there are some elements flagged as "highlighted", so the element size is 2x2 (double width and height), now I want only 25 elements on this page, and the other 3 elements should be displayed on the next page, because of the optic.
How can I do this?
Or an communication with the view, that only 25 elements are rendered, or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Change the pager limit to 25?

Comment: Not on every page are elements which are highlighted, or there can be 2 or 3 elements on a page which are highlighted.
Example: 28elems, 25elems, 28elems, 22elems, ...

Comment: You'll probably need to build a custom pager plugin for views, I don't think you'll be able to convince the built-in plugin to behave like that

Comment: Okay, but where/how should I save or give the param to the next page, how many elems already rendered on page 1 and 2, if I am on page 3?

Comment: Like I say, you'll need to write a custom Views pager. The logic you use within that pager will be pretty complicated so I won't speculate on how exactly you'd accomplish it - depends exactly what you're trying to do. The logic/algorithm you need is nothing to do with Drupal so I'd advise you work out how you'd do this outside of Drupal first, then you can work out how to get it into views

Comment: Thanks for your answers. :)
I will try something like that:
A view with no pager limit. (but I set an global string of 28 elements per page)
I will go the frontendpage of the view (lets say page 3).
Instead of rendering the result of this view, I will grep (views_get_view_result) the result of the exactly same view with an offset of X and an pager limit of 28 as argument (X I know because I will loop the results of the view and know how many elements on page 1 and 2 are highlighted [last page divided by my global string +3 per highlighted element])
Maybe this will work.
Sorry for my english :|